# How can I enqueue and dequeue a class with QPoint pointer members?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to use a QQueue to store objects of my class. The class has members that are pointers to QPoints. I store an object of my class in a QQueue and retrieve it.

```cpp
#include <QQueue>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QDebug>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int x, int y);
    ~Foo();
    QPoint bar;
    QPoint* baz;
    //Q_DISABLE_COPY(Foo)  // not sure whether I need this
};

Foo::Foo(int x, int y): bar(x, y) {
    baz = new QPoint(x, y);
}

Foo::~Foo() {
    delete this->baz;
}


int main(void) {
    QQueue<Foo> queue;
    Foo a(5, 6);
    qDebug() << "a.bar.x()=" << a.bar.x() << ", a.baz->x()=" << a.baz->x();

    queue.enqueue(a);
    Foo b = queue.dequeue();
    qDebug() << "b.bar.x()=" << b.bar.x() << ", b.baz->x()=" << b.baz->x();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a.bar.x()= 5 , a.baz->x()= 5
b.bar.x()= 5 , b.baz->x()= 0
09:46:59: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

If I comment out `delete this->baz;` in the destructor I get what I would have expected:

```
a.bar.x()= 5 , a.baz->x()= 5
b.bar.x()= 5 , b.baz->x()= 5
```

---

Could someone explain what's going on here? It seems to me that the destructor to Foo is being called early. Thanks.

Comment: Read about [rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). It seems `Foo` instances are copied (as shallow copy) when they are enqueued/dequeued, so many instances refer to the same `baz` pointer and it is deleted more than once by `delete` in `Foo` destructors. You need to implement copy operators (constructor/assignment) that do deep copy of `baz` member.

Comment: QPoint is not QObject

Comment: @eyllanesc ah yes you're right, I'll update the question
Edit: looks like you got there first :)

Comment: @OvercastPiranha627 Also as a basic rule: as a last option you must create dynamic memory, QPoint has a copy constructor so it is not efficient to create pointers.

Answer (score 1):

[Read about "The rule of three/five/zero"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Basically default copy constructor is not valid in your case and it is used when you are adding `Bar` to `queue` (pass by value).
As a result there are two `Bar` objects where `baz` is pointing to same `QPoint`. When one object dies nothing bad happens, but when copy dies code tries to release something what was already released. This leads to a crash.

Answer (score 0):

`QQueue` stores a copy of the added object. So, at this line `Foo b = queue.dequeue();` destructor of `Foo` is called. You can ensure in this in debugger. Add breakpoint to `Foo` destructor and debug.